# Cell/range as a parameter for function, and calculating average in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to recreate the sum function that adds up values within a range, I also want it calculate the average, I will add more calculations later on but so far I'm only testing out the sum portion before doing the average. But I'm not sure how to pass the cells as a parameter into the function, also not sure on how to take the average of the sum since I don't know how to count the number of cells in between the two given cells in the parameter.

```
Function ASDF(x As Range, y As Range) As Double
```

is what I have tried, it doesn't work when I try something like

```
ASDF = "=sum(x:y)"
```

it gives me an error in the cell I tried to do the function =ASDF(A1:A30) with "#VALUE!"

Basically how do I pass those cells into my function and use them?

What is the correct way to do this? Also is there a way of finding out how many cells there are in between if given the two bounds of the range? so for example if I'm given a1 and a30 as parameters is there a way to get that there are 30 cells?

Comment: your input and output aren't the same. it should be `=ASDF(A1, A30)`. Also your function has the wrong return. it should be `ASDF = "=SUM(" & x & ":" & y & ")"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see what you're trying to do there - I'm kind of surprised it didn't just return the string "=sum(X:Y)" in all your cells - possibly the error might be due to the fact that you've defined your function with two ranges (x and y) and you're only using one to call it (A1:A30)

If you want to set your function up to look at one particular range at a time, then it's best to set it up instead as

```
Function ASDF(x As Range) As Double
```

Otherwise, you can use X and Y as before, but this would mean when calling the function you need to enter "=ASDF(A1,A30)" Which to be honest doesn't really add anything to your functionality.

With the setup above, to actually get the sum you need to do the following:

```
ASDF = worksheetfunction.sum(x)
```

And to get the number of cells you need to refer to

```
ASDFCount (example variable name) = x.Count
```

Comment: it didn't return the string because `ASDF` is returning a `Double`

Comment: @Tyeler that's true as well - testing appears to show that either one would cause the error

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work, It seems I didn't understand how range worked in VBA, my code below gets the average like I want it to, I just had to iterate through the range one by one, I was falsely assuming that there was some one line command that could calculate the # of cells in a range for me.

```
Function ASDF(r As Range)

    Dim cell As Range, total As Double, count As Integer
    For Each cell In r
        total = total + cell.Value
        count = count + 1
    Next cell
    ASDF = total / count

End Function
```

Comment: are you literally just after the average? There's a function for that, =AVERAGE()

You can even call it in VBA-

Worksheetfunction.Average(range) - although if you need the sum/count for other things as well that's fair enough

Comment: *Very Nice* .................you only need more than one parameter if you are handling disjoint ranges or ranges from separate worksheets.

Comment: @danl No, I'm going to do more calculations later on but since I didn't know how the range worked I was simply testing it out to make sure I understand how everything works by doing the basics

Comment: You can make your current code a lot shorter and faster by replacing the `For`-loop with this: `count = r.Rows.Count` and using the `average` function to get the total.

Answer (score 0):

adapt your code with the following

```
ASDF=application.worksheetfunction.sum( range(x, y))
```